# Find all elements in column 1 where column 2 is x

Tags: awk

I have a 2x14000000 dataframe where column 1 is a series of (essentially) unique elements, and column 2 is repeated.

Example.data:

```
rs564192510     TRIT1
rs564192510     MYCL
rs146746778     NFIA
rs142596889     KIAA1614
rs142596889     XPR1
rs4437820       NOC2L
rs7542092       NOC2L
rs28444699      NOC2L
```

I'm looking for a (preferably awk?) command that will pull out the unique elements in column two and write all elements of corresponding elements of column one after it. So for Example.data, you'd get Outcome.data below:

Outcome.data:

```
TRIT1    rs564192510     
MYCL     rs564192510     
NFIA     rs146746778
KIAA1614 rs142596889
XPR1     rs142596889
NOC2L    rs4437820 rs7542092 rs28444699
```

I intially tried to do this in R using melt and reshape, but the dataframe is too long to process easily.

Comment: `perl -ane 'if ($F[1] ne $p) { print "\n$F[1]"; $p = $F[1] } print " $F[0]"; END { print "\n" }'`

Comment: Well that works upsettingly quickly and well. Please write as an answer so I can credit you!

Comment: So you're only looking for someone to write your code for you?

Comment: That's why you're getting downvoted. stackoverflow isn't a "write code for me" service.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90047/discussion-between-joni-and-melpomene).

Comment: I'm not going to delete this thread, because the perl solution above is elegant and useful (column 2 needs to be sorted). 

But I'm not ashamed to ask for code. It helps me learn how to write it myself. Sorry if that upsets you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

awk to the rescue!

```
 awk -vOFS="\t" '{a[$2]=a[$2]?a[$2] FS $1:$1} END{for(i in a)print i OFS a[i]}'
```

concatenate values in array indexed by field 2.  Special for first element to eliminate extra field separator.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not the most elegant, but this should work

```
#! /bin/sh -u

previous=""
while read ln; do
    line=( $ln )
    if [ $line[1] == $previous ]; then
        printf " %s " "${line[0]}"
    else
        printf "\n%-10s %s " "${line[1]}" "${line[0]}"
        previous=$line[1]
    fi
done < /dev/stdin
```